# How to deserialize a collection of Polymorphic objects using Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, polymorphism

I´m trying to deserialize a collection of object that are hierarquical and come from an API call, however I have to analyse the incoming JSON to decide how to do this deserialization.

I have created a custom deserializer for the objects accordingly and decide how to do the serialization. However it throws me an exception.

I will omit the getters and settters for simplicity

```
  public  abstract class Message implements Serializable {
    protected String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    protected MessageType type;
    protected String to;
    protected final static long serialVersionUID = 875082919667906573L;
  } 

  public class SelectContentMessage extends Message {
    private SelectContent content;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 875092919667906573L;
  }

public class SelectContent implements Serializable {
    private String text;
    private List<Option> options=  new ArrayList<Option>();
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = OptionDeserializer.class)
public abstract class Option implements Serializable {
    protected int index;
    protected final static long serialVersionUID = 434566339626802052L;
 }

 @JsonDeserialize(as = SimpleOption.class)
 public class SimpleOption extends Option {
     private String value = "";
     private final static long serialVersionUID = 334566339626702052L;
 }

 @JsonDeserialize(as = ComplexOption.class)
 public class ComplexOption extends Option {
     private Value value;
     private final static long serialVersionUID = 434566539626702052L;
 }

 public class Value implements Serializable {
      private String title;
 }

 public class OptionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Option> {

    @Override
    public Option deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
        TreeNode node =  mapper.readTree(p);
        ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode)node;
        Class<? extends Option> instanceClass = null;
        if (root.has("value") && root.get("value").has("type")) {
            String type = root.get("value").get("type").asText();
            switch (type) {
            case "text/plain":
                instanceClass = SimpleOption.class;
            default:
                instanceClass = ComplexOption.class;
            }
            return mapper.readValue(p, instanceClass);            
        }
        instanceClass = SimpleOption.class;
        return mapper.readValue(p, instanceClass);
    }
 }
```

Below there are examples of 3 JSONs that must be deserialized by this classes:

```
{"id":"1","to":"1042221589186385@messenger.gw.msging.net","type":"application/vnd.lime.document-select+json","content":{"header":{"type":"application/vnd.lime.media-link+json","value":{"title":"Welcome to mad hatter","text":"Here we have the best hats for your head.","type":"image/jpeg","uri":"http://petersapparel.parseapp.com/img/item100-thumb.png","aspectRatio":"1:1"}},"options":[{"label":{"type":"application/vnd.lime.web-link+json","value":{"text":"Go to our site","uri":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com/view_item?item_id=100"}}},{"label":{"type":"text/plain","value":"Show stock"},"value":{"type":"application/json","value":{"action":"show-items"}}}]}}

{"to":"553199990000@0mn.io","type":"application/vnd.lime.collection+json","content":{"itemType":"application/vnd.lime.container+json","items":[{"type":"application/vnd.lime.media-link+json","value":{"text":"Welcome to our store!","type":"image/jpeg","uri":"http://www.petshoplovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/CUIDADOS-B%C3%81SICOS-PARA-CRIAR-COELHOS.jpg"}},{"type":"application/vnd.lime.select+json","value":{"text":"Choose what you need","options":[{"order":1,"text":"See our stock"},{"order":2,"text":"Follow an order"}]}}]}}

{"id":"7577560d-5937-4115-9f82-96c0d705ea5f","type":"application/vnd.lime.select+json","content":{"text":"Choose ","scope":"immediate","options":[{"text":"App ","previewText":"App","value":"App","index":0,"type":null},{"text":"⤴️ Menu","previewText":"⤴️ Menu","value":"⤴️ Menu","index":1,"type":null}]}}
```

And I´m getting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.NullNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode (through reference chain: ai.blip.httpintegration.models.messages.SelectContentMessage["content"]->ai.blip.httpintegration.models.messages.SelectContent["options"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])
```

Comment: What class is `{"index":0,"text":"Quero saber mais","previewText":"Quero saber mais"}` supposed to be mapped to?  If it's a `ComplexOption`, shouldn't it be like `{"index":0,{"title": "some title"}}`?

Comment: Your `POJO` structure does not fit to given `JSON`. `text/plain` means it is a `SimpleOption`? Do you have any other example how `type` could look like?

Comment: @MichałZiober thx for the help.

I just put better examples of the JSON that might come as body of the request.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusBianchiSantos, are we talking about https://limeprotocol.org/index.html?

Comment: @MarcusViniciusBianchiSantos, have you found solution for this problem? Do you stil need help with that?